# Smarty Template: How to make get <li> elements from different <ul> to be next to each other

Tags: html, css, templates, smarty, prestashop

in my prestashop website, i am using "Advanced Homepage Product List" module.
I got rid of the  titles that has the category name because i just want my items sorted and I didn't need the category names displyed.

This is how it is now.
[image]

I want to have the "Buy Fudgee Bar..." item right next to the "Buy 2 bioderm coolness.." item. If i can get them to be just one , they can be right next to each other right? :o

how do i do this??

Below is the Smarty template file for the module:

```
{assign var=zItem value=0}
{if isset($isian) AND $isian}
        {foreach from=$isian item=cat name=productCat}
    {assign var=zItem value=$zItem+1}

            {$products=$cat.produk}
            {if isset($products) && $products}
                        {counter name=active_ul assign=active_ul}
                        {include file="$style" class='homefeatured tab-pane' id='prodcat' active=$active_ul}
                        {/if}


         {/foreach}
        {else}
                <p>{l s='No featured products' mod='prodcat'}</p>
        {/if}
```

It doesn't really have to be a  in the end. as long as "buy fudgee bar chocolate" goes right next to "buy 2 bioderm coolness.." AND if there's another category, it shouldn't leave blank spaces. The products should be displayed continiously.

Answer (score 0):

I can not see that these `<ul>`'s have different `<li>`'s
If the `<ul>`'s are in the same `<li>`'s then try something like this in your css:

```
ul li{
   display: inline-block;
}
```

or

```
ul li{
   float:left;
}
```

If they are in other `<ul>`'s try to give the complete `<ul>` tags a `float: left` or `display:inline-block`

Comment: The first 2 items in the image are part of one <ul>

the 3rd,4th and 5th item in the image(the ones on the bottom) are from a different <ul>

I tried putting float:left;display:inline-block; on both the first <ul> and the second <ul>, it didn't do anything.

Comment: float:left; and display:inline-block;

Doesn't help when i put it on the <li>s either.
I guess because they are in different <ul>s..
I think the smarty template really has to be modified so it doesn't put them on different <ul>s. I have no knowledge about smarty templates though :(

Answer (score 0):

If the li elements have not the same height and your want to align them differently. 
Add this:
ul li{vertical-align:top;}

Vertical align values can be: top, middle, bottom. Bottom is the default value.

Comment: They are from different <ul>s.
I want them last item of the first ul and the first item of the 2nd ul to be next to each other.

I am thinking of modifying the Smarty Template so they'll simple be in one <ul> but i dunno Smarty :o